# Python: np.where with multiple condition

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have df and I try create new column, where numbers from one column is some phrase.
I use

```
df["Family"] = np.where(df["Qfamilystatus"] == 1, "Не замужем / Не женат", "Замужем / женат / живу в гражданском браке", "Разведен/ живем порознь", "Вдовец / вдова")
```

I mean `1 - Не замужем / Не женат, 2 - Замужем / женат / живу в гражданском браке, 3 - Разведен/ живем порознь, 4 - Вдовец / вдова`
But it return `TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (5 given)`
Is another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) function by `dictionary`.

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Qfamilystatus':[1,2,3,4]})
print (df)
   Qfamilystatus
0              1
1              2
2              3
3              4

d = {1:"Не замужем / Не женат", 
     2:"Замужем / женат / живу в гражданском браке", 
     3:"Разведен/ живем порознь", 
     4: "Вдовец / вдова"}

df['new'] = df.Qfamilystatus.map(d)
print (df)
   Qfamilystatus                                         new
0              1                       Не замужем / Не женат
1              2  Замужем / женат / живу в гражданском браке
2              3                     Разведен/ живем порознь
3              4                              Вдовец / вдова
```

Then you can new column convert to `category`, which save memory:

```
df['new'] = df.Qfamilystatus.map(d).astype('category')
print (df)
   Qfamilystatus                                         new
0              1                       Не замужем / Не женат
1              2  Замужем / женат / живу в гражданском браке
2              3                     Разведен/ живем порознь
3              4                              Вдовец / вдова

print (df.dtypes)
Qfamilystatus       int64
new              category
dtype: object
```